# Can't see `Roadmap` feature in Jira Software

Tags: jira

I do not know why I can't see `Roadmap` feature in Jira.

[image]

And in the project setting, I can see that `Roadmap` is auto enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Jira Cloud Scrum project, the **Roadmap** feature is configured per **board**.

To enable it for your board, you will likely need to:

1. ​Navigate to your desired **board**
2. Click the **three dots** in the top right corner
3. Click **Board Settings**
4. On the left hand **Board Settings** click **Roadmap**
5. Toggle the **Enable the roadmap for  board** button